# viewDidAppear event is not called when working with application unit test framework in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, testing

I setup an application with unit test framework in Xcode. After that, I wrote test code for the app.
For example,
`[welcomeViewController next:welcomeViewController.nextButton];`
which will push another `viewController` in `UINavigationViewController`.

However, the view in simulator is not changed and the `viewDidAppear` event for the other viewController is not called either. I checked that `viewWillAppear` event of the other `viewController` is called correctly.

Is this a bug of unit test framework or am I wrong in utilizing unit test framework?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: look at this answer to [iOS testing controllers with Cedar] http://stackoverflow.com/a/14513163/1040553